# Comics series, where the protagonist is a blind warrior on a medieval world (some glacial terrain)

Tags: story-identification, comics

The protagonist is a male blind warrior, has one sword and is really good at fighting. I don't remember if he has some special power or something like this... The history is set in a medieval world and in some comics in a glacial terrain.

This warrior has one apprentice with him, but I don't remember if it is a male or a female, only that he/she is young.

I read this comic in Spanish, between 2004 and 2005, in print. It didn't seem like a Japanese or otherwise Asian comic.

Comment: What language did you read it in? Was it a western or an eastern comic? Online or in print?

Comment: Sounds like [Zatoichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatoichi), but I don't know of any comics based on him.

Comment: @Gallifreyan i read it in spanish, but i'm sure that shave a english version. I don't know if is a eastern or western comic and i mean a print version. And sorry but is not Zatoichi this warrior has a bandage in eyes and don't has japanese or asiatic style.

Comment: You might take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fictional_blind_characters to see if any of them match up.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots None of here is my blind warrior :(

Comment: You might also check out the few comics listed on TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlindWeaponmaster

Comment: @yesterday nothing in your post... But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is *Warlands: Age of Ice* (2003).

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2775117-warlands-volume-3):

> Warlands is set in a sword-and-sorcery world inhabited by humans and a variety of mythical races, caught up in an endless series of wars against evil forces. In this volume, a woman from the past returns to tell the heroes they must continue the fight to save the world. Although the great ice dragon Eganko was killed and cast into the ocean during the previously chronicled war, her blood is slowly freezing the world, causing the seasons to stop changing.

The warrior that you mean is Zeph: young assistant to Delezar, who was killed. He always wears a mysterious **blindfold**. He is now an archmage. [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlands).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please add some details as to why it matches.

Comment: WOW, I read about this, and yes this is the Comic Series. The Warrior is  Zeph, and  he have a bandage in her eyes.Thanks for the answer man.